# Redefine function body in javascript

Tags: javascript

Given some javascript like this:

```
var doSomething = function() { return 1 };
doSomething.someProperty = "a";
```

How can I redefine the function so that, e.g., `doSomething()` returns 2, but without losing any additional properties defined on it?
I've found plenty of answers about this sort of thing for OOP, but I'm not using "new" here, just calling the function directly.

Comment: It's not possible unless you overwrite the function or the function explicitly returns one of its own properties (e.g. `return doSomething.someProperty`).

Comment: The only way I can think of is storing the old function in some temporary variable `temp` and then after reassigning the original variable to something new, copy the old function's properties e.g. using `Object.assign`.

Comment: var doSomething = function(num=1) { return num;};
    doSomething.someProperty = "a";

Comment: or use eval of some JS string var in function body and alter the string as needed : )
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!) ... but slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the properties from the original function to a new function:

Original Answer:

```js
function redefineFunction(oldFn, newFn) {
  Object.assign(newFn, oldFn);
  return newFn;
}

// Original function and properties
var doSomething = function() { return 1 };
doSomething.someProperty = "a";

// Redefine
doSomething = redefineFunction(doSomething, function() { return 2 });

console.log(doSomething);
console.log(doSomething());
console.log(doSomething.someProperty);
```

Simplified using `Object.assign` without needing a function:

```js
var doSomething = function() {
  return 1
};
doSomething.someProperty = "a";

// Redefine
doSomething = Object.assign(function() {return 2}, doSomething);

console.log(doSomething);
console.log(doSomething());
console.log(doSomething.someProperty);
```

Comment: This seems like a reasonable solution. Can you explain the purpose of `Object.create(oldFn).__proto__`, rather than just using oldFn directly?

Comment: @Gannet, this creates a new object based on the original function, then I can take the `__proto__` of that copy, and assign it to the function that was passed in

Comment: Right, but why not just do `Object.assign(newFn, oldFn)`?

Comment: @Gannet, you're right, in this case, there is no difference. Generally when cloning objects, it's best to create a new object so that new references are created.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip. So in this case it just boils down to this? `doSomething = Object.assign(function() { return 2 }, doSomething);`

Comment: @Gannet, yep, that should do it

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```js
  var doSomething = function() {
    return doSomething.returnVal;
  }
  doSomething.returnVal = 1;    // Without this, doSomething returns undefined

  console.log(doSomething());   // <= 1
  doSomething.returnVal = 2;
  console.log(doSomething());   // <= 2
```

If you want to make some more dramatic change to the function (i.e. altering the algorithm that it runs rather than just a data value within it), then probably the best approach would be to create an entirely new function and copy the properties of your old function to it:

```js
  function copyProperties(source, destination) {
    for (var property in source) {
      destination[property] = source[property];
    }
  }

  var doSomething = function() {
    return 1;
  }
  doSomething.someProperty = "a";

  var doSomethingElse = function() {
    return 2;
  }
  copyProperties(doSomething, doSomethingElse);

  console.log(doSomethingElse());             // <= 2
  console.log(doSomethingElse.someProperty);  // <= a
```

Comment: I think he wants to be able to redefine the function more generally, changing the return value was just an example.

Comment: @Barmar, I agree--I added an additional possible solution to cover that case.

Comment: Thanks, this will be a good solution when Object.assign is not available.